# Can Torment-only legendaries drop in Greater Rifts?

Tags: diablo-iii

Can "Torment-only" legendaries drop in Greater Rifts? If so, is it restricted to Greater Rift level 8 (the equivalent of Torment 1) and up?

Comment: I've gotten plenty of class sets already from GRs, but I haven't done one below level 8 to know for sure if its for all levels.

Comment: As it requires clearing a torment rift first in order to get the key, I would *assume* that even the lower greater rifts can drop torment only legendaries. I had a shadow's grasp drop in a level 3 greater rift from the guardian and that is listed here: http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/10189299133 as being a torment only legendary. Couldn't find any official posts on it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

I set out today to test this out, and after killing the rift guardian on rift 1, got Marauder's Boots

[image]